# $scope and counting children of an element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, and I have a jQuery background so that could influence my way of thinking the problem.
In order to do DOM manipulation through `transclude` directive (i.e. adding a specific class) I need to know how many children (or maybe siblings) has a generic element.
What I mean is I would like to set a class on all children, based on an algorithm that counts the number of children themselves.

This is what I tried so far

```
var main = angular.module("Main",[]);

function utilities(){
    this.consoleScope = function($scope){
        return $scope.children().length;
    };
}  
main.service("utilities",[utilities]);
main.controller("Prova",["$scope","utilities",function($scope,utilities){
    var self = this;
    self.consoleScope = function(){
        return utilities.consoleScope($scope);
    };
}]);
```

But even if it runs without errors, it doesn't retrieve the information I wanted. I can comprehend this is not the *right* way to do this, but I can't see any other way. What could I try?

Comment: Yes you are very biased to jQuery :).  Use `ng-class` to add a class based on certain conditions.  You should be managing the data to control that class in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've mixed up your application logic with your DOM logic. Ideally when talking about children you'd be assigning or creating these based upon a data set or collection.
e.g.

```
//In your controller
$scope.data = someDataSet;
```

from there you would implement your algorithm based upon your data set.

```
//still in your controller
$scope.algorithm = function(data){
   ... implement your logic ...
   // e.g.
   return data.length > 5;
}
```

Now in your UI mark up you would use `ng-class` and an expression to assign the class on any element that needs the class.  Your controller shouldn't know about your classes.

```
<div ng-class="(algorithm(data)) ? 'trueClass' : 'falseClass'" ></div>
```

This is a really simple implementation but you can extend it pretty easily.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Actually, the class I want to add does not depend on true/false conditions, but from the very number of children of an element.
Furthermore, I can't comprehend the first part in which you talk of a _data set_: what does that mean, that if I want/have to generate my HTML dinamically, I have to assign its structure to some sort of variable (most probably db)?

Comment: Ok, so data set just refers to an object or collection of objects, that would be used to create your dynamic view, as your view is just a mark up representation of your data (this is one of the biggest changes from JQuery to using an MVC framework).  The ng-class example is just a simple example, but ng-class can take an infinite number of conditions and configurations.

Comment: "as your view is just a mark up representation of your data" - this made my day. Correct me if I'm wrong: i could write no HTML, store all of the hierarchy necessary to the compiler in objects inside AngularJS and creating it through `transclude`-type only directives. Am I right?
(Ok, maybe that's not the best approach: _simplify when possible_ is still advisable)

Comment: That's more or less correct, angular is geared towards HTML generation and manipulation, but i've seen it used against regular XML or for crud with JSON (Atypical use cases).  Within you application everything should be developed and run independent of the UI, which is a stated goal for angular as it encourages separation of concerns. Which means you can store all the heirarchy, data structures, and activity is typical angular and then have it bind against whatever you're building as a UI.